# Trying to print bitmap image with thermal receipt printer, nothing happening

Tags: thermal-printer

I have a Star TSP100 receipt thermal printer. I installed the drivers and it shows up in "my printers", the computer seems to recognize it. I am a photographer and I thought it would be cool to print some bitmap images on this thing. I saved my image as a bitmap and tried printing from microsoft paint but no luck. When I plug in the usb it prints out a test receipt but that's it. Any advice? I know I probably have to do some coding which I'm down for. Thanks.

Comment: Your question lacks information to allow others to research and answer the problem. Use these help articles to refine your question. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to make it better

Comment: The help article tells you what to do. Or please refer to the articles that have been answered/approved among other articles assigned the same tag.